# Catching a custom Exception thrown by a WebMethod on ASP.NET WebService

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, exception

I have a classical asp.net web service (asmx) and a web method in it. I need to throw a custom exception for some case in my web method, and I need to catch that specific custom exception where I call the web service method.

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public HelloWorldOutput HelloWorld(HelloWorldInput input)
    {
        try
        {
            // My Code
            return new HelloWorldOutput();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new HelloWorldException("Hello World Exception", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Input, output and exception classes as a sample:

```
public class HelloWorldInput { }
public class HelloWorldOutput { }    

[Serializable]
public class HelloWorldException : Exception
{
    public HelloWorldException() { }
    public HelloWorldException(string message) : base(message) { }
    public HelloWorldException(string message, Exception inner) 
        : base(message, inner) { }
    protected HelloWorldException(
      System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
      System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context) { }
}
```

In the client side, I need:

```
public static void Main()
{
    WebService service = new WebService();
    try
    {
        service.HelloWorld(new HelloWorldInput());
    }
    catch (HelloWorldException ex)
    {
        // Do sth with HelloWorldException
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Do sth with Exception
    }
}
```

However, I cannot do that because when I add the web service reference on the client, I have service class, input and output classes, but I do not have custom exception class.

Also another problem is that, I have also problems with serializing Exception class (because of Exception.Data property implements IDictionary interface)

Is there a way to do this in my way, or am I in a completely wrong way, or is there something I miss about fundamentals of web services?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ASP.NET Web Service can throw any type of exception: SoapException, HelloWorldException or soever. However, the exception is serialized into a SOAP Fault element, and regardless of the type of the exception thrown in the service, the exception is converted into a SoapException while deserialization. Hence, it is not possible to catch the HelloWorldException with my catch block in my question, even if I deploy the HelloWorldException to the client.

For an ASP.NET client, the only way is to catch the exception as SoapException and handle it by its `Actor` or `SoapFaultSubCode` property.

I've basically solved my problem as below:

Web Service:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public HelloWorldOutput HelloWorld(HelloWorldInput input)
    {
        try
        {
            // My Code
            return new HelloWorldOutput();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new SoapException("Hello World Exception",   
                 SoapException.ServerFaultCode, "HelloWorld", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public static void Main()
{
    WebService service = new WebService();
    try
    {
        service.HelloWorld(new HelloWorldInput());
    }
    catch (SoapException ex)
    {
        if(ex.Actor == "HelloWorld")
            // Do sth with HelloWorldException
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Do sth with Exception
    }
}
```

Together with the document which Bryce Fischer wrote in his answer; these msdn documents also has helpful information about throwing and handling web service exceptions.

[How to: Throw Exceptions from a Web Service Created Using ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6d0x301k.aspx)

[How to: Handle Exceptions Thrown by a Web Service Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wteyzs5.aspx)

Comment: You need to set customErrors mode='RemoteOnly' or 'On' in your web.config

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds492xtk%28VS.71%29.aspx) may be of help. Looks like you'll get a SoapException, but you can inspect the details to determine if its your class or not.

Side note, to have access to "HelloWorldException", you can pull it out into a seperate assembly and deploy that on the client...

Comment: The link you have shared was very helpful Bryce. Thanks. That help me realize the behaviour of web service exceptions. However, deploying the exception class to the client will be a late choice for me. I will think about the subject for a while. Thanks a lot.